# PyTorch: Zero all elements of vector except top k?

Tags: python, pytorch, top-n

I am trying to create a new activation layer, let’s call it topk, that would work as follows. It will take a vector x of size n as input (result of multiplying previous layer output by weight matrix and adding bias) and a positive integer k and would output a vector topk(x) of size n whose elements are:

```
              x_i (if x_i is one of the top k elements of x) 
topk(x)_i = 
              0 (otherwise)
```

While calculating gradient of topk(x), top k elements of x should have gradient 1, everything else 0.

How should I implement this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`torch.topk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.topk.html) for this:

```py
k = 2
output = torch.randn(5)
vals, idx = output.topk(k)

topk = torch.zeros_like(output)
topk[idx] = vals
```

```py
>>> topk
tensor([1.0557, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.4562, 0.0000])
```

Note that while the `'values'` of `topk()` are differentiable, the `'indices'` [**are not**](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/backward-through-topk-operation-on-variable/9197/4?u=iacob) (similar to how argmax is not a differentiable function).

Comment: Does not work on multiple dimension tensor?

Comment: @KazamiMichiru "Returns the `k` largest elements of the given `input` tensor along a given dimension. If `dim` is not given, the last dimension of the *input* is chosen."

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find the top-k values and their indices along the last dimension of the tensor.
topk_values, topk_indices = torch.topk(x, k, dim=-1)

# Create a mask tensor with the same shape as 'x', initialized with zeros.
mask = torch.zeros_like(x)

# Set the top-k values to their original values in 'x'.
mask.scatter_(-1, topk_indices, topk_values)
```